# Some searches don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I would like to set up three search forms but the two(name and place) of the three don't work. I don't understand why it makes them different because the codes for them are almost the same.

☆members_controller

```
def index
if !checklogin? then return end #
  if params[:name].present?
   @members = Member.where("name like ?" , "%" + params[:name] + "%")
  else
   @members = Member.all 
  end

  if params[:place].present?
   @members = Member.where("place like ?" , "%" + params[:place] + "%")
  else
   @members = Member.all 
  end

  if params[:field].present?
   @members = Member.where("field like ?" , "%" + params[:field] + "%")
  else
   @members = Member.all 
  end

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json
  end 
 end
```

☆members_index(view)

```
<div class= "form_index">
  <%= form_tag({:action=>"index"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
   <div class="from_field_index">
    <%= label_tag 'name', '名前検索:' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
   <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
 <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class= "form_index">
  <%= form_tag({:action=>"index"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
   <div class="from_field_index">
    <%= label_tag 'place', '活動場所検索:' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'place' %>
   <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
  <% end %>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class= "form_index">
  <%= form_tag({:action=>"index"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
   <div class="form_field_index">
    <%= label_tag 'field', '言語分野検索:' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'field' %>
   <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

☆command-field search

```
Processing by MembersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "field"=>"rails", "commit"=>"検索"}
  Member Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" 
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE (field like '%rails%')
  Member Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  Rendered members/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
```

☆command-place search(bad case)

```
Started GET "/members?utf8=%E2%9C%93&place=%E6%A8%AA%E6%B5%9C&commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2"     for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-03 13:47:20 +0900
Processing by MembersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "place"=>"横浜", "commit"=>"検索"}
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" 
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  Rendered members/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 73.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to preserve `@members`:

```
  # Rails 4
  @members = Member.all 

  # Rails 3
  @members = Member.scoped

  if params[:name].present?
   @members = @members.where("name like ?" , "%" + params[:name] + "%")
  end

  if params[:place].present?
   @members = @members.where("place like ?" , "%" + params[:place] + "%")
  end

  if params[:field].present?
   @members = @members.where("field like ?" , "%" + params[:field] + "%")
  end
```

Note there is just one call to `all`. Note also that in Rails 4 you would use `all`, while in Rails 3 you would use `scoped`.

Comment: I think @members.where will execute sql query again. Instead use @members.select! {|member| member.name.include? params[:name] }

Comment: no, `where` does not execute query, it returns a Relation. Same for `all`.

Comment: oh I see, OP is using Rails 3, I think `all` in Rails 3 does not return a relation.

Comment: yes, all will return array in rails 3. If we call where on resulted array, sql query will execute. That is what I am experiencing.

Comment: did you see `scoped` use in my answer?

Comment: scoped will solve this issue. Also use elsif  instead of 3 if.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42388/discussion-between-thaha-kp-and-juanpastas)